# Convert an Object to other in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 employees Formats. I need to make relation between field names.

So, I will receive a JSON in the request with other names, than my object name:

```
{
    "id":288,
    "apellido_paterno":"Name1",
    "apellido_materno":"Name2",
    "nombre":"First Name",
    "RFC":"JIGJ710729B37",
    "CURP":"JIGJ710729HNEMNN00",
    "NSS":"11067101607"
    ... and 20 more fields
}
```

On the other hand, I have to fill an object whose fields are:

Model Employee

```
id,plastname,mlastname,name,rfc,curp, nss, [ and 20 more fields ]
```

I could do :

```
    $employee->name = $request->nombre;
    $employee->plastname = $request->apellido_paterno;
    $employee->mlastname = $request->apellido_materno;
    $employee->name = $request->nombre;
    $employee->rfc = $request->RFC;
    $employee->curp = $request->CURP;
    $employee->nss = $request->NSS;
```

and put it in a function, but for a lot of field, it can be a lot of work.

Is there any way to do it more efficiently in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `create` static method of your employee model. Something like this:

```
Employee::create([
    'name' => $request->nombre,
    'plastname' => $request->apellido_paterno,
    // etc.
]);
```

More about mass assignment here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#basic-inserts (in "mass assignment" section).

*Anyway, you will have to match your request fields with your model properties.*